# How do I report a link that has nothing to do with the topic?

Tags: support

Not sure if I phrased the question correctly, feel free to change it. But hopefully the following image will show what I mean.

[image: Linked post seems unrelated]

So the post in the link section talks about Git, although there is a reference to robots.txt, but the main topic of the question seems unrelated to the current post which is clearly about the robots.txt file not Git. What to do to report/remove it?

Comment: The linked questions are the questions that were literally linked to, either the other question to this one, or this one to the other, by a link in a question, answer, or even a comment. Someone included a link for some reason, and there's no reason to remove the link. It's not damaging anything by being there, and it must exist because someone did include a link to that question, or possibly linked to that question from the other.

Comment: All right, understood. I thought it was manually picked by someone.

Comment: As Davy wrote, that section lists links from comments, answers and the question itself. Only problem is that I cannot find any reference to that question on [the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15119760). It might be in a deleted comment?

Comment: @Justastudent Other way 'round. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383521/git-2-versions-of-one-file?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment48857214_30383521 The other question has a comment that links to the first.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question. The OP seems to want to help improve the site, and it's not exactly immediately obvious how those links work. Why all the downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383521/git-2-versions-of-one-file?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment48857214_30383521) (also found by [Mike M.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363166/how-do-i-report-a-link-that-has-nothing-to-do-with-the-topic#comment556209_363166)) on [Git 2 versions of one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383521) has an url to [What is the smartest way to handle robots.txt in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119760/what-is-the-smartest-way-to-handle-robots-txt-in-express) and that leads to an entry in the Linked table.

The Linked table list is two-way, in the sense that it doesn't matter on which Q/A pair the link is posted. It will list them on both questions.

The Linked table list isn't updated. So removing the comment that caused the link to be created will not remove the entry from the linked table. Once an entry is in, it stays there.

There is a [moderator tool](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6680180#6680180) to rectify possible mishaps that can occur but only CM's know where it is:

> Probably not even intended to be a mod tool as such; in the early days when there were only a few mods, Jeff tended to just add anything that wasn't super-dangerous to admin tools instead of making things dev-only ([source](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6680191#6680191))